# AWS Role - provide AWS key to EKS pod as env variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I would like to access role's aws key and secret within EKS pod but have been unsuccessful so far.

The idea is to retrieve them from instance metadata and inject them as ENV variables into pod. I have already linked service account to role and specified it in pod deployment but it doesn't look like key is automatically available as ENV in pod.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Using ak/sk is not a good practice, you can use [IAM role for service account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) to bind the RBAC in k8s with the IAM roles .